# Is WebRTC cheat-proof for multiplayer HTML5 game?

Tags: javascript, html, p2p, webrtc

I'm creating a multiplayer HTML5 P2P game; and I would like to use WebRTC to communicate without the server.

I know that there is no way to prevent from JS modification from the browser, but anyway, I would like to know : is WebRTC secure enough ?
Can a user can modify on-the-fly what the packet contains ? Or does DTLS+SRTP prevent from that ? If I communicate with another player, how can the user B be sure that the packet has not been modified since it has been written ?

I would say that it is, because TLS involves that there is Diffie-Hellman key-exchange; and all the communications should be AES + signed with SHA. So I'm guessing that is secured.

Am I wrong ?

Comment: Of course not.  It is fundamentally impossible to trust data from a hostile client.

Comment: If the connection is encrypted, you can be sure that the packed was not modified. However, if you don't trust your peer client, you cannot trust *what* was written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a user can modify on-the-fly what the packet contains?

No.

> Or does DTLS+SRTP prevent from that? If I communicate with another player,
>   how can the user B be sure that the packet has not been modified since
>   it has been written?

Yes.

However, if you don't trust A you cannot trust *what* he did write.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing on the client is cheat-proof. Keep in mind that the browser is just a means for users to send messages to your server (or to other users in your case). A determined malicious individual could fabricate the messages himself without a browser.

Encryption exists to prevent a third party from reading/altering messages sent between two individuals. It can in no way prevent one of the two individuals from sending other messages than you intended and correctly signing them.

What you can do is validate on each client that the messages received from the other "make sense", that they fit in the context they are received in. A trivial example would be a chess game where a player sends a message that would teleport his piece in a place where it cannot legally move. In this case if both players know the state of the game (necessary i think), then the second player can and should determine that the move was invalid and somehow respond to that (either terminate the game or attempt to recover from the invalid state).